# tagging built artifacts in Bamboo CI server

Tags: continuous-integration, bamboo

We are using bamboo as our integration server. During each build it produces binary packs of our products. Some of the built artifacts then goes in to QA.

Is there a way to retain build artifacts of a certain build job number, irrespective of the global build expire configuration. For an example, at some point we identify one of the built artifacts as release candidate.

The QA should be able to download that specific pack even after one weeks time. Right now we are copying the build artifacts from CI server to some other machine. It is a script, but still it is a manual process.

In Hudson there is an option called 'keep this build forever'.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your version this is possible by applying a label to it.  Under a plan's configuration on the "Miscellaneous" tab, you can set a label which can then be used to prevent a build from expiring.

For example, our system has builds that can get labelled "SaveBuild" which then prevents their expiry.

Comment: That is still at a plan level, and could be done with the override build expiry as well - keeping all artifacts.   But Jenkins for instance allows you to view an artifact after a build has completed and mark it for indefinite retention.

Comment: Eddie's comment is wrong: This answer works perfect. The plan level config is only for setting what label should be used for retaining build (artifact, result and logs). (This could be done in the global settings as well.) Then, a label can be added PER BUILD, for marking each build for retaining build artifacts.